# Date format issues while assigning to a variable in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

My script fails because of the the date format on the server.

```
declare @lastDay as datetime
declare @endDay as datetime

set @lastDay = '2012-07-12 18:00:00.000'
set @endDay = '2012-07-16 18:00:00.000'

Select getdate(), @lastDay, @endDay
```

In the above code the data I assigned is in (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm) format.  But the sqlserver takes this as (yyyy-dd-mm hh:mi:ss.mmm).

But when use the getdate() function sql return in (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm) format.  The problem occurs only when I assign the value.

The same code works fine on the pc but fails on server.

The result I get on the server for the above code is

```
2012-07-17 15:34:30.627    2012-12-07 18:00:00.000      NULL
```

and with error message

```
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

I know I can use the convert function, but I few hundreds for dts jobs which need to be schedule on the server now, which is not a quick solution for me to look at each package.

I guess I need to change some settings on the server to consider  (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm) by default. Please help me if someone know the solution to fix this.

Comment: Check the server's locale settings, perhaps? Tried this on my 2008r2 install and the dates came back as expected y-m-d, not y-d-m.

Comment: @murty did you test your newly accepted answer when you are not logged in to the machine? I'd be very careful with using ambiguous format for dates against this and other servers, where you may not have control over the regional settings, and may not be able to keep the user logged in 24x7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution for this, its in the user profile.  I changed the default language for the user from "British English" to "English" and every thing is normal.

Also thanks for your quick responses.  I gain some additional knowledge from your responses.

Thanks.

Comment: It's normal while that user is logged in. Did you test the behavior after the user has logged out? Which user is "the user"?

Answer (score 2):

YYYY-MM-DD does not work when, say, language is FRENCH.

You can say:

```
SET @lastDay = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-12 18:00', 120);
```

But much safer to use a safer format, and avoid the need to convert:

```
SET @lastDay = '20120712 18:00:00.000';
```

Or if you really want the dashes, add the T separator, which prevents the regional setting from overriding:

```
SET @lastDay = '2012-07-12T18:00:00.000';
```

The nice thing about fixing the format is that let's say you "fix" this by changing the server's regional settings. That "fix" only works until someone else changes the settings back, because it breaks something else, or until you move your code to another server. Passing in a safe format bypasses all these issues.